# How can I use AND condition in IF EXISTS in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'X' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Y') 

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Z' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'A')
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[X] 
        SET Y= (SELECT inst.[A] FROM [dbo].[Z] s WHERE s.[B] = [dbo].[x].[B]);
END    
    GO
```

I want to combine the 2 IF confitions and perform the update only when both of them are satisfied. Is there some way in which I can club 2 IF EXISTS?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

Simple:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'X' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Y') 
AND EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'Z' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'A')

BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[X] 
        SET Y= (SELECT inst.[A] FROM [dbo].[Z] s WHERE s.[B] = [dbo].[x].[B]);
END    
GO
```

Comment: Or, actually looking at your code, it will work as written -- the 2nd IF is nested under the 1st. Just add tabs:)

Comment: Also, you should include TABLE_SCHEMA in your INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS query, otherwise you will get wrong result if the same table name exists in a different schema.

Comment: G, what if the column A or column Y does not exist or is deleted? I am getting an error in that case.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Invalid column name 'A'.

Comment: user811433: if the tables exist then SQL Server tries to "bind" the statement, i.e. resolve all object and column references. And if the columns do not exist you get an error. In that case you need to do dynamic SQL: EXEC ('UPDATE [dbo].[X] SET Y= (SELECT inst.[A] FROM [dbo].[Z] s WHERE s.[B] = [dbo].[x].[B]);')

Comment: When I try the dynamic SQL like the one above - I see more or less the same error as before.
The multi-part identifier "s.A" could not be bound.

Comment: I added the EXEC inside the IF conditions above and I was able to get rid of the error. Thank you @Vlad G

Answer (score 6):

No need to select all columns by doing SELECT *  . since you are checking for existence of rows , do SELECT 1 instead to make query faster.

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
              WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'X' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Y')

IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
          WHERE  TABLE_NAME = 'Z' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'A')

    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[X] 
            SET Y= (SELECT inst.[A] FROM [dbo].[Z] s WHERE s.[B] = [dbo].[x].[B]);
    END    
        GO
```

Comment: You'll never get a record from your query, unless somehow `TABLE_NAME` can be both `'X'` and `'Z'` at the same time. Repeat for `COLUMN_NAME`. Also, *since you are checking for existence of rows , do SELECT 1 instead to make query faster.* SQL Server is smarter than that.

Comment: No, then the `UPDATE` would run if either `X.Y` or `Z.A` existed, not both.

Comment: Regarding performance, as I understand it the select list for an `EXISTS` query is only validated when the query plan is being built, but has not effect on the execution. The query optimizer simply builds a plan that tests for the existence of a row meeting the specified requirement(s). For a stored procedure with a cached plan, don't worry about it. Though my personal preference is to select `42`, you'll find that `1 / 0` or `NULL` work just as well. Even `30 / -3 / 5`, which would ordinarily result in a divide-by-zero error, works.

Answer (score 0):

Change the title and description empty

```
UPDATE `li_categories`
  SET description = CASE
    WHEN description = '' THEN CONCAT('optional text ', title, ' optional text')
    ELSE description
    END
WHERE
 id
```